# Foundry is not able to install solc

Tags: foundry, forge

Hi I just installed ubuntu 22 lts and then installed foundry.

`forge init` works fine, but on `forge test` or `forge build`it gets stuck on installing solc i have tried to cancel the operation and redo it, restart machine and tried to remove and reinstall foundry but nothing seems to work.

does anyone have an idea of what could be the trouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install solc separately: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/installing-solidity.html . In my case I installed solc (globally) on my system (win10) by using npm:

```
npm install -g solc
```